# Java records and field comments

Tags: java, java-14, java-record, java-16

When we use classes in Java it's very simple to add JavaDoc/comment for each class field/method:

```
class Product {
    //Product unique identifier
    private int id;
}
```

If we migrate these classes to Java records then it's unclear what is the the best practice to write comments/JavaDocs in this case:

```
record Product(int id, String name, double price) {
}
```

Because now all the fields are declared in one line.

Comment: For javadocs see [this corresponding openjdk ticket](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8225055).

Comment: What’s the point of hiding the information that “id” is supposed to mean “Product unique identifier” within the source code of the class?

Answer (score 17):

Well, you have two choices concerning documentation, either use the Javadoc on record level, or use a block comment, I've used both hereunder

```java
/**
 * My record example
 *
 * @param string does stringy things
 * @param integer does integery things
 */
public record Example(
        /*
          Does stringy things
         */
        String string,
        /*
          Does integery things
         */
        int integer
){};
```

Here is an example of Javadoc from the JDK itself

```java
/**
 * A serializable cartesian point.
 *
 * <em>This example illustrates the documentation of a serializable record.</em>
 *
 * @param x the x coordinate
 * @param y the y coordinate
 */
public record SerializablePoint(int x, int y) implements Serializable { }
```

And here is an example with a comment block (even though it does not have any parameter)

```
public record NoWarningRecord(/* no components */) {
    // No explicit constructor; use canonical one.
}
```

Answer (score 6):

`id`, `name`, and `price` in the second snippet are not fields, these are record components. Answer by [Yassin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67375192/6099347) already mentioned how to achieve it but just for the sake of completeness, here is how you do it:

```
/**
 * A very complex Product description.
 *
 * @param id    Product identifier; appears in "Record Components".
 * @param name  Product name appears; in "Record Components".
 * @param price Product price; appears in "Record Components".
 */
public record Product(int id, String name, double price){}
```

The following would be ignored by standard doclet:

```
public record Product(
  /**
   * This comment would be ignored.
   */
  int id,
  /*
   * Ignored
   */
  String name,
  // Ignored
  double price) {}
```

If you have a field, then you can add Javadoc to it:

```
public record Product(...) {
  /**
   * Max Product price, appears in "Field Summary".
   * <p>
   * Appears in "Field Details".
   */
  public static final double MAX_PRICE = Integer.MAX_VALUE >> 2;
}
```

To add Javadoc to the canonical constructor, you can use compact style:

```
public record Product(...) {

  /**
   * Product's compact canonical constructor, appears in "Constructor Summary".
   * <p>
   * In "Constructor Details".
   *
   * @param id    Product identifier, appears in "Constructor Details"
   *              not in "Record Components".
   * @param name  Product name, appears in "Constructor Details"
   *              not in "Record Components".
   * @param price Product price, appears in "Constructor Details"
   *              not in "Record Components".
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException Allowed price range
   *                                  ({@code 0.0D}, {@link Product#MAX_PRICE}]
   */
  public Product {
    if (price <= 0 || price > MAX_PRICE) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
```